# How do I add summary statistics into a long dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a count variable to my long dataframe in R. For each participant, I have a few hundred observations and I want to add an individual count value once for each participant. I have computed a count variable with dplyr, but there are two problems with this:
Firstly, the counts are provided as 'true' or 'false' (counting condition met or not), whereas I am only interested in the true values.
Secondly, when trying to add these count values back into the original dataset, I receive a replacement error, since (obviously) the new variable is much shorter than the original.
In order to tackle the latter issue, I have first created an empty variable in the dataset, filled with NAs. So at the end of this, I want to have only one value for each of the participants and the remaining cells filled with NAs.

Here is my current code:

```
dfl$Ntimer <- NA # generating an empty NA column 

Ntimer <- dfl %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  count((!is.na(Timer)))

Ntimer

dfl$Ntimer <- Ntimer
```

For Ntimer, the output looks as follows:

```
                  participant (!is.na(Timer))   n
300:                      LY9                       TRUE  60
301:                     LYJ4                      FALSE 344
302:                     LYJ4                       TRUE  35
303:                     LYJ5                      FALSE 336
304:                     LYJ5                       TRUE  21
```

So I would like to not have the FALSE in the table.

When I then try to add the data back to my NA filled dfl$Ntimer column, I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Ntimer, value = list(participant = c("LYN9",  : 
  replacement has 304 rows, data has 66619
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Thank you and very best wishes,
Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `count` (which summarises the data to return a single row per groupings and thus the assignment on the original data will not work as the nrow are different unless we do a join), we may create the column with `sum(!is.na` in the original data

```
library(dplyr)
dfl %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  mutate(n = replace(rep(NA, n()), 1, sum(!is.na(Timer)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thank you very much for this suggestion! It worked in the sense that it did compute a Timer count for all participants, however, unfortunately I still have the issue that all rows were filled with this count. So for example, for participant LX4, I may have 150 rows and each of them now contains the count 9. However, I only want one row to contain the 9 and all other rows to be filled with NA. Is there some way to achieve this?